# ROW Headers not appearing SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report which is a tablix without any details group or any group for that matter. I have a row headers which are based on an expression that I would like to repeat on each of the page. But within the report, I do not see these headers being repeated. Is it because I have no grouping? 
[image]

[image]

What am i doing wrong? How can I get these to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to create a static header without a row group within a tablix. However, this is possible within a matrix. I had to re-create the table as a matrix. Then I was able to add the static row header to each page.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on `Tablix>Tablix Properties`

You will see the different options for Row Headers and Column header.